# Preservation of definiteness dominance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$, symmetric, and positive definite. We write $A\succ 0$ and $B\succ 0$. Suppose that it is also true $A\preceq B$, that is, $B-A$ is positive semidefinite. I'm wondering if the following are true:
$$
\forall D: n\times m:ADD'A\preceq BDD'B\tag{$*$}
$$
and
$$
\forall d: n\times 1:Add'A\preceq Bdd'B\tag{$**$}
$$
My intuition is that we are essentially squaring $A$ and $B$, then multiplying the results by the same nonnegative entitiy. So the original relation between $A$ and $B$ themselves ($A\preceq B$) should be preserved and I expect ($*$) and ($**$) are both true but I cannot produce a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither claim is true.

Let $m=n=2$.

Let $A,B$ be given by
$$
A=
\pmatrix{
3&2\\
2&3\\
},\;\;\;
B=
\pmatrix{
5&1\\
1&3\\
}
$$
Then $A$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2-6x+5$, and $B$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2-10x+24$, so $A,B$ are both positive definite.

For $B-A$, we have
$$
B-A=
\pmatrix{
2&-1\\
-1&2\\
}
$$
which has characteristic polynomial $x^2-4x+3$, so is positive definite.

Letting $D$ be given by
$$
D=
\pmatrix{
2&1\\
1&1\\
}
$$
we get
$$
BDD'B-ADD'A=
\pmatrix{
68&32\\
32&11\\
}
$$
which has characteristic polynomial $x^2-79x-276$, so is not positive semidefinite.

Letting $d$ be given by
$$
d=
\pmatrix{
1\\
0\\
}
$$
we get
$$
Bdd'B-Add'A=
\pmatrix{
16&-1\\
-1&-3\\
}
$$
which has characteristic polynomial $x^2-13x-49$, so is not positive semidefinite.

Thus, both claims are disproved.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, how did you come up with these examples?

Comment: @yurnero: I intuited that the claims were probably not forced, so I set up some matrices with a few unknown entries, and found conditions on the unknowns needed to break the claims.